# Attribute dropdown on Catalog grid in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, attributes, dropdownbox

I would like to add a dropdown to the product in the list view (frontend) like this:
Example at www.workout.be
When you select something (different taste, size or weight) the price should adjust.

Anyone out there who can tell me how to do this?
I've been searching for weeks.
("Show in product list" is activated)

Comment: you have to add configurable products

Answer (score 0):

you need to add configurable products check this

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

to Show the option on category product list page check this

http://www.catgento.com/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/

Comment: Hello Rohan, that I did and it works (check www.ftns.be) I get a dropdownbox on the product page, but I need to get it on the catalog page, where you have an overview of the products, just like on the website www.workout.be